# Creating a new list from a percentage of the previous list?

Tags: python

Hi guys so I have a program here that has the user enter a sequence of numbers that is then covered to a list

```
total = int(input("How many numbers do you want to enter? "))

myList = []
for i in range (total):
    n = int(input("Enter a number >> "))
    myList.append(n)

print ("The list is")
for i in range(total):
    print (myList[i])
```

it works fine and is compatible to the rest of the program but what i need is to make a new list from myList however the new list must only have data that belongs to the sub-range 5%- 95% of the original data

i'm not really sure how to do that...using python 3.2.3 IDLE

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "sub-range"?

Comment: Are you attempting to discard the early and late entries by the user (the first and last numbers) or do you want to discard the low and high values?  The first is in an answer already, the second calls for sorting or indexing, or averaging, or whatever other criteria you have for what passes and what does not.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
In [72]: L = range(100)

In [73]: L[int(len(L)*0.05):int(len(L)*0.95)]
Out[73]: 
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
```

Comment: This is good if he wants positional cuts, but I believe he's after removing the lower / upper values that the user entered data (just a guess).

Comment: The question was a bit ambiguous. This is a good start, upon which he can build what he wants

Comment: okay seriously this program should work but python 3.2.3 IDLE just hates me, when i printed the result, it came out 0, 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little randomness to pick any amount of values from the list:

```
total = int(input("How many numbers do you want to enter? "))
import random as ran
vList=[]
myList = []
for i in range (total):
    n = int(input("Enter a number >> "))
    myList.append(n)

print myList

x=ran.uniform(1, len(myList))
x=int(round(x))
for i in range(x):
    y=ran.choice(myList)
    myList.remove(y)
    vList.append(y)

print vList
```

That should work :)